# Android Not Resolving Volley Method.GET

Tags: android, get, android-volley

I am new to Android, just trying to use Volley as instructed in the Android website but don't seam to get this right.

This line seems to causing the trouble:

```
StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(VoiceInteractor.Request.Method.GET, url,
```

and the error is:

```
Error:(32, 92) error: cannot find symbol variable Method
```

MainActivity.java:

```
package com.jorc.volley;

import android.app.VoiceInteractor;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.android.volley.RequestQueue;
import com.android.volley.Response;
import com.android.volley.VolleyError;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.StringRequest;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.Volley;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

          final TextView mTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text);
            // Instantiate the RequestQueue.
                    RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
                    String url ="http://www.google.com";

            // Request a string response from the provided URL.
                    StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(VoiceInteractor.Request.Method.GET, url,
                            new Response.Listener<String>() {
                                @Override
                                public void onResponse(String response) {
                                    // Display the first 500 characters of the response string.
                                    mTextView.setText("Response is: "+ response.substring(0,500));
                                }
                            }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                            mTextView.setText("That didn't work!");
                        }
                    });
            // Add the request to the RequestQueue.
                    queue.add(stringRequest);
    }
}
```

Comment: is your service method type get or post??

Comment: That seemed to solve the problem, thanks ρяσѕρєя K

Answer (score 3):

Use `Request.Method.GET` from Volley library to `StringRequest` instead of [VoiceInteractor.Request](http://developer.android.com/intl/es/reference/android/app/VoiceInteractor.Request.html)  which is used for `voice interaction requests` :

```
StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET,... url,
```

Answer (score -1):

This is what android's official documentation says about volley requests 
[Sending a Simple Request](http://developer.android.com/training/volley/simple.html)

**Simple Volley Request**

```
 final TextView mTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text);
    ...

    // Instantiate the RequestQueue.
    RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
    String url ="http://www.google.com";

    // Request a string response from the provided URL.
    StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET, url,
                new Response.Listener<String>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(String response) {
            // Display the first 500 characters of the response string.
            mTextView.setText("Response is: "+ response.substring(0,500));
        }
    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            mTextView.setText("That didn't work!");
        }
    });
    // Add the request to the RequestQueue.
    queue.add(stringRequest);
```

and if you are sending a JSON Request then you can do it like this and this is my own way to send JSON Request using Volley Library

**JSON Request using Volley**

```
public void myJSONRequest(){
  JSONObjectRequest request = new JSONObjectRequest(
   Request.Method.GET,
   url, 
   null,
   new Response.Listener<JSONObject>(){
     public void onResponse(JSONResponse response){
      // Do you parsing 
     }
   },
   new Response.ErrorListener(){
     public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError volleyError){
      // handle your errors
     }
   }
  );
  if(request != null){
    requestQueue.add(request);
  }
  else{
     Log.d("ERROR", " Volley Request Failed");
  }
}
```

Comment: Arent you just copying the answer above?

Comment: @Amir no it is just excitement because i am also new in android i recently learn this thing (Volley) before that i was using HttpUrlConnection class that was too much complex and volley is little easy thats why i answer this question nothing else and i write my code in this style (Request.Method.GET) i taught you did not write the statement correctly